# Creating standard deviation for ratio of two medians

Tags: standard-deviation, bootstrap, median

I'm working on a project and am creating an index based on two medians (median cost/median income), with a small number of observations (<100). I'm trying to figure out how to properly calculate the standard deviation of such a ratio. I have the margin of error for median income, but not the median cost. If I read my stats correctly, standard deviations of medians are about 1.25 times the standard deviation of mean. But, how would I go about constructing the SD for this proportion of two medians?

My initial thought is to treat it as proportion and use the binomial SD formula. However, this doesn't seem to take into account that the proportion is constructed from two medians. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: You could try bootstrapping your metric of interest?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I'm not sure I explained this correctly, and now I'm thinking a simple mean/SD might be OK. Each obs. has an index var(med. cost/med. income) and each obs. is a region. The goal is to get the average of this "index" variable and then, for each observation (region), use "# SD away from average" to get a sense of the spread of this index. Is it OK to just create this index, get the mean of this index, and create associated SD for each region (observation)? This would not require any bootstrapping, but I am wondering how appropriate it would be use mean/SD for this.

Comment: You could do that. However,  be cautious when drawing inferences from your results. You need to check your metric is roughly normally distributed. I do believe you should try bootstrapping an estimate of the standard error, and then try comparing that to the one you get using the formula for the standard error.

Comment: Thanks ralph! I will definitely try the bootstrapping, and I think I can bootstrap the variance? I'll compare it to the sample variance I find. I'm not so concerned about the SE, since the "# SD away from average" is supposed to be more descriptive to see the variation in the index across regions, rather than being concerned about the actual average of the index. Should I be more concerned?? Thanks :)

Comment: If there is any chance the income could be zero or negative, then it's likely this ratio has no expected value at all and therefore has an infinite standard error.  Bootstrapping would not cure this problem.

Comment: If you assume that ln(cost) and ln(income) have a bivariate normal distribution with known parameters, then median(ln(cost)) - median(ln(income)) also has an approximately normal distribution. Then you can calculate the parameters for the distribution of the difference, and plug them into the standard lognormal formulas to get a standard deviation for median(cost)/median(income).